# Can you build a URL in Restangular with multiple variables?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular

I am trying to build a resource in Restangular with a URL that has multiple variables.  The server variable is set, so I need to figure out how to do this client side.

This is the URL that I was using in ngResource:

```
'/api/v1/reports/shipped-orders/:reportDate/:orderType'
```

There isn't really any nesting past shipped-orders, it's just passing parameters through the URL.

I tried chaining them like:

```
_reports.one('shipped-order', '2013-11-04').one('', 'bulk')
```

But that turned out a url with double slashes in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently ran into this problem.  Here's what I did:

```
myApp.factory('myRestService', ['Restangular', function(Restangular) {
    return {
        myFunction: function(varA, varB, varC) {
            var path = "rest/primaryPath/" + varA + "/" + varB + "/" + varC;
            var restObject = Restangular.all(path);
            var thePromise = restObject.getList();

            return thePromise;
        }
    };
}]);
```

By building the path myself, I was successfully able to use more than one variable and get a result from the Java Rest Service I was using in my project.

Comment: Awesome and thanks! I ended up just using straight $http, but I'll definitely give this a shot next time.

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to do the following:

`Restangular.all(varA).all(varB).all(varC);`